# Left-Hand Side (LHS) and Right-Hand Side (RHS) entities meaning in Git and (Git-Python)

Tags: python, git, diff

I would like to know how Git-Python API interpretes LHS and RHS values represented by numbers /codes. I am especially intrigued with this matter since in 99.99% cases that number either queals to 100664 or is not present at all (any explanation?).
Additionally referring to Git-Python API, is there any way to obtain detailed diff info for example using unique "hash codes" present in output (I presume that they point to such info). By detailed I mean e.g. printing lines of code that have been added /deleted /modified, numbers of lines of code etc.

```
INPUT:

import git
repo_dir = [...]
repo = repo = git.Repo(repo_dir)

n = [...], i = [...]
current_commit = repo.heads.master.commit
older_commit = list(repo.iter_commits('master', max_count = n)[i]
diff_info = current_commit.diff(older_commit.hexsha)

diff_output_str = ''
for diff_obj in diff_info:
            diff_output_str += diff_obj.__str__()

print(diff_output_str)
```

```
OUTPUT:

=======================================================
lhs: 100644 | f32fff73df39e9653b48268494051db816c69f6e    # "hash-codes"
rhs: 100644 | c9a18c1318f7feddc6b6017d22e05f630f5c5651    
root_dir/sub_dir/example_file.txt                         # relative filepath
=======================================================
```

Comment: `644` is the mode; if the file were executable, it would be `755` instead. That is to say, what the merge contains is the identity of the object on each side, and the bitmask with permissions for how that object is identified on the filesystem.

Comment: ...that way the object storage is decoupled from the filesystem structure -- you can have two copies of the same file with different names or different permissions, but there's only one instance of the content in the store.

Comment: ...so no, the "hash codes" don't point to a detailed diff; they point to a *specific copy of the content* on each side that was the input to the merge. Of course, a textual diff can be generated off the content, after it's looked up (and I'd expect the Python API to have a method for doing that, but I don't know it / haven't looked it up here).